# Mod that makes dropped items stand out?

Tags: mods, the-elder-scrolls-iv-oblivion

One thing that annoys me with Oblivion (even though it *is* realistic) is that when you kill a mob, and they drop their weapon(s), you have a hard time finding them in, say, tall grass.  Especially when you're on a hillside (and Cyrodil seems to be very hilly :D), stuff rolls/slides down, landing sometimes quite far from the actual fight.

So: I'd love it if there was a mod that made them stand out.  Maybe (to keep it "realistic") having to quest for a special spell.  Or does such a spell exist?  Either way, something that made them show up, like "Detect Life".

Comment: I never had a problem with it..I personally quite liked the fact the weapons would be physics objects. I haven't played in a while, but can't you find the weapon on the corpse anyway?

Comment: @The Communist - I'm not sure what decides it, but weapons (and shields) can either be on the corpse, or get knocked away individually.

Comment: @RavenDreamer In my experience, even items that get knocked away are still on the corpse.

Comment: @Raven @Duck Whether the weapon was equipped upon death determines whether it's dropped on the ground (and might roll down an entire mountain range) or whether it's in the corpse-container.

Comment: Sometimes it isn't just the loot you can't find. If I played the PC version rather than the 360 version, I'd almost want a mod that would let me plant a flag on a corpse in the middle of battle. The number of times I left a lootable corpse "right over here somewhere" ...

Comment: @Dave - it's worst when you fight several skeletons or storm atronarchs which explode into their constituent components -- you have to search the pile femur by femur, never sure which bone belongs to which mob.

Comment: @Raven @Dave yeah, I know the pain.  Just yesterday I fought some mobs at one of the Orrery quest camps.  Two I found quickly... and then "dammin, where did the third fall?!"  I did find the corpse... think I missed one dropped weapon, just the final trigger for this question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a few spell-based mods that do this.

**[Detect Item](http://tesnexus.com/downloads/file.php?id=25179)** adds a spell that puts a particle effect on items, making them obvious on the ground or behind rocks. It's a "beta" quality release and it's been years since, so it's unlikely to get polished up, but it works. *Requires OBSE v0017 or later.*

**[Finders Keepers](http://tesnexus.com/downloads/file.php?id=14316)** adds a whole lot of spells for detecting different objects by adding shaders/particle effects. It also has spells that can detect different NPC aspects, such as Vampirism, disposition, etc. Some can be used simultaneously, and some will cancel others—so you can, for example, have Detect Weapons and Detect Keys running simultaneously, but casting Detect Alignment will cancel any other Detect spell. Clearly it's not as convenient as a one-size-fits-all Detect Items spell, but this might feel more "realistic" for some players. As a bonus, though, many of the item-detection spells will reveal things inside chests as well as on the ground. *Requires OBSE v0013a or later and the latest official patch.*

Some of the big magic overhaul mods may also include item-detection spells, but I haven't found a comprehensive guide to their included spells quite yet.

Answer (score 6):

If you're primarily worried about finding things in tall grass, it's a simple matter of pressing the '~' key, typing "tg", picking up the formerly hidden items, and typing "tg" to turn the grass back on.