# Stop enemies dropping items on death

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iv-oblivion

Enemies often drop equipped weapons, shields and torches when they die, which often results in the player having to search a large area full of tall grass or the items falling through the floor and disappearing forever. Is there a way to disable this behavior and make the corpses hold onto the mementos of their life for my looting convenience?

Comment: You mean something like what the [Unofficial Skyrim Patch](http://www.iguanadons.net/Unofficial%20Skyrim%20Patch%20Version%20History.html) modifies in Skyrim? "*NPCs will no longer drop weapons or shields as separate objects, as these are never cleaned up which greatly adds to save bloating and litters the game world (the items will still appear to be dropped, but will access the corpse's inventory to be taken and be cleaned up with the corpse if left).*"

Comment: @galacticninja yeah, that would be great.

Comment: @Ender As per these meta posts, there is now *no* blanket rule/policy that mod recommendations are off-topic: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5547/closed-mod-recommendation-skyrim-question-can-this-question-be-improved-and and http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6828/is-mod-rec-really-am-umbrella-category-that-we-want-to-use-or-is-it-confusing

Comment: Related: [Mod that makes dropped items stand out?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/22879/4797)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there is no mod that does this for Oblivion. What I normally do is turn off the grass layer (press <kbd>~</kbd> to open the console then type `tg`, <kbd>enter</kbd>) when I want to find equipment that drops on the ground.

This takes immersion away but it's better than spending a couple of minutes looking for a weapon in the grass only to find it on the bottom of the hill. There is no hot key for it – I already looked for it pretty hard – but if you can make macro's this would be much more comfortable. You might want to look into an autohotkey script, it's quite easy to understand.